# Why timeout is used for ifdown command?

Tags: timeout

In one of the script i have seen the ifdown command with timeout

```
timeout 20 ifdown eth0 --force
```

for what purpose the timeout may be useful?

Comment: Read `man timeout`

Answer (score 1):

In case there is an `ifup` active it would interfere with the `ifdown` command. Waiting 20 seconds would avoid this (`ifup` is likely to finish or error out without 20 seconds).

As an example: [OpenVSwitch](https://sebastian.marsching.com/wiki/Linux/OpenVSwitch) uses it.